# SP13: Custom List Searching

Tags: 2013, search, custom-list

I created a custom list.  Within the custom list I can search on every column except the following: People and Groups and Date and Time.  I have checked the Search Settings for the custom list and everything looks to be setup correctly.  Is this a feature in SP13 that is not possible to return search results on those columns?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have checked this an it will return people picker field results in list search but when i searched for date (modified) it does not return results. I believe it probably isn't doing a text search on date column.

Comment: @Manu That's odd.  I am not sure why the People and Group column type is not returning results for me.  Thanks for troubleshooting on your end.